# How to Make Compiler Assume `nullable` by Default

Tags: objective-c, swift, interop, objective-c-nullability

Since Xcode 6.3, types in Objective-C can be marked with `nullable` or `nonnull`, [here is Apple's blog post about this](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25).

Problem is, when neither is specified, then the compiler imports the Objective-C code as *implicitly unwrapped* into Swift, e.g. `NSView!`. So when an object actually *is* nil, then it will crash when accessed from Swift. This does **not** produce a compiler error.

As this is extremely prone to fail, **I'd like the compiler to assume everything from Objective-C by default as `nullable`**, except when otherwise specified via `nonnull`, or the audited region macros `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN / END`. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no way around adding nullability annotations in order to get rid of implicitly unwrapped optionals.

I wrote a [script that finds all non-annotated headers](https://github.com/fabb/check_nullability) which can also be added as a build phase, so no headers are overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for but from Xcode 7, you can turn on `CLANG_WARN_NULLABLE_TO_NONNULL_CONVERSION` in LLVM complier settings by passing `-Wnullable-to-nonnull-conversion` flag in complier flag.
This will warn if there is a implicit conversion from `nullable` to `non-nullable` conversion.

Comment: Unfortunately does not help if you do not have nullability annotations

Answer (score -2):

Since the macro is defined as:

```
#define NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN _Pragma("clang assume_nonnull begin")
#define NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END   _Pragma("clang assume_nonnull end")
```

It may be worth trying to see if there's a corresponding `assume_nullable` macro.

```
#define XX_ASSUME_NULLABLE_BEGIN _Pragma("clang assume_nullable begin")
#define XX_ASSUME_NULLABLE_END   _Pragma("clang assume_nullable end")
```

I only did a quick test to check if this pragma fails compilation, which it didn't. But I haven't tested whether this produces the expected results in Swift.

Comment: Yeah, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent preprocessor macro for that: http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Preprocessor.html

Comment: A variable marked with `nonnull` is safe and `nullable` one is not, so `nullable` mark should be specified every time.

Comment: Nice try... pity it doesn't work. I agree it is much needed, and in real-world programming, there are many structures that accumulate Lot's of nullable properties (things you may/may-not find in a parsed input (say JSON, XML, Plist etc.)  and it makes perfect sense to NS_ASSUME_NULLABLE_BEGIN/END on groups of these. It has nothing to do with "safety" when your world is ObjC and when you write daemons and frameworks - that are NOT even available from Swift.